# React Native array prop confusing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have two components, a parent (`ManySpace`) and a child (`OtherComponent`). `OtherComponent` renders two `ManySpace` components with two different arrays for the `manyspace` prop.

I don't use const and let because using variables outside the render scope  like this

```
onSubmitEditing1 = () => {
    if (secondinput) { this.secondref.focus(); }
    else if (thirdinput) { this.thirdref.focus(); }
    else { Keyboard.dismiss(); }
};
```

MANYSPACE1 and MANYSPACE2 render is perfect, but confuse the first ManySpace and second ManySpace component array contents how I solve this problem thanks.
hope I to explained the my problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
let MANYSPACE;
let icerik;
let firsttext;
let firstinput;
let answer1;
let answerlength1;
let secondtext;
let secondinput;
class ManySpace extends Component {
    render() {
        MANYSPACE = this.props.manyspace;
        icerik = MANYSPACE[0].icerik;
        firsttext = MANYSPACE[0].firsttext;
        firstinput = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput;
        if (firstinput) {
            answer1 = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput.answer1;
            answerlength1 = answer1.length;
        }

        secondtext = MANYSPACE[0].secondtext;
        secondinput = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput;
        if (secondinput) {
            answer2 = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput.answer2;
            answerlength2 = answer2.length;
        }
        return ()
    }
}
```

--My other component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
const MANYSPACE1 = [
    {
        icerik: 'lorem ipsum',
        firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
        firstinput: {
            answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        secondtext: 'lorem ipsum'
    }
];
const MANYSPACE2 = [
    {
        icerik:'lorem ipsum',
        firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
        firstinput: {
            answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        secondtext: 'lorem ipsum',
        secondinput: {
            answer2: 'lorem ipsum'
        },
        thirdinput: {
            answer3: 'lorem ipsum'
        }
    }
];  
class OtherComponent extends Component {
    <ManySpace
        manyspace={MANYSPACE1}
    />
    <ManySpace
        manyspace={MANYSPACE2}
    />
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: confuse the first ManySpace and second ManySpace component array contents, for example  MANYSPACE1 answer1 = abc , MANYSPACE2 answer1 = cba , two ManySpace component answer1 output is same not expected  values